# How to access Microsoft Word document functions or Macros using Perl Script

Tags: vba, perl

The below code to be accessed the `Convert` vba functions for the MS Word Document. But I couldn't able to achieve this: Please advice which state I did wrong.

`The code usage is We are already created one functions or Macro in VBA named as 'Convert' hence the Perl script to execute the same.`

CODE:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Variant;

# Create a Word application object
my $word = Win32::OLE->new('Word.Application', 'Quit') or die "Cannot create Word application object: $!";

# Disable alerts and make Word application visible
$word->{DisplayAlerts} = 0;
$word->{Visible} = 1;

# Open a Word document
my $doc = $word->Documents->Open("d:\\sample.doc");

# Access the menus
my $menus = $doc->CommandBars;

# Find the "Convert" menu
my $fileMenu = $menus->Controls("Convert");

# Check if the menu is found
if ($fileMenu) {
    print "Menu Found: Convert\n";
    # Perform operations on the menu, such as accessing its items
} else {
    print "Menu Not Found: Convert\n";
}

# Close the document and quit Word
$doc->Close();
$word->Quit();
```

Some one could help me on this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify your question, please show how you added the menu. What errors do you get? What is the expected output? See [mcve] for more information

Comment: @HåkonHægland I will update the question soon.

Comment: @HåkonHægland I am very sorry its not menu, Its called functions in the VBA macro's like EquationsConvert, FormatEquations etc.,